# How to catch windows turnoff in application without forms (and not console)?

Tags: delphi-2010

So i have application without forms with endless loop.
In the loop i check something and do application job.
So i need to turn off my application when User turn off his PC.

Had found information about WM_QUERYENDSESSION and WM_ENDSESSION but don't know how to catch them.
Have anyone any examples how to set hook on this and catch this message?

Had try to set hook, but i think i don't have enough experience.

I used SetWindowsHookEx function to set hook.
Is there any other way to catch windows turnoff messages?

Here is application prototype:

```
program Hoook;

{$APPTYPE GUI}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Messages,
  WinTypes,
  Windows;

var a:boolean;

begin
//Here we must set hook
a:=true;
while a=true do
   Sleep(1000);
   //Check something
   //Do something
end.
```

Comment: Create a hidden top level window and let it receive these messages

Comment: any code samples or links?

Comment: There's loads on the web